# ActiveModel::Errors shows different output for to_h and to_hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

For a class like this, `ActiveRecord::Errors` for `to_h` and `to_hash` gives two different outputs although they are alias of each other.

```
class Person
  # Required dependency for ActiveModel::Errors
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def initialize
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
  end

  attr_accessor :name, :phone, :age
  attr_reader   :errors

  def validate!
    errors.add(:name, :blank, message: "Name cannot be nil") if name.nil?
    errors.add(:name, :blank, message: "Name is mandatory") if name.nil?
    errors.add(:phone, :blank, message: "Phone cannot be nil") if phone.nil?
  end
# The following methods are needed to be minimally implemented

  def read_attribute_for_validation(attr)
    send(attr)
  end

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
    attr
  end

  def self.lookup_ancestors
    [self]
  end
end

person = Person.new()
person.validate!
person.errors.message => {:name=>["can't be blank", "can't be blank"], :phone=>["can't be blank"]}
person.to_hash => {:name=>["can't be blank", "can't be blank"], :phone=>["can't be blank"]}
person.to_h => {:name=>"can't be blank", :phone=>"can't be blank"}
```

Why is this difference between `to_h` and `to_hash` for this class?

Answer (score 2):

they are not really the same, 'to_hash' is an implicit conversion while 'to_h' is an explicit conversion.
implicit conversion provides you with detail data-type and data is not lost during conversion. However, if you only want the basic data, just go with 'to_h' or the explicit.

reference: [implicit-vs-expicit](https://zverok.github.io/blog/2016-01-18-implicit-vs-expicit.html)